# Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<DetectLanguage.DetectResult[]>' to 'DetectLanguage.DetectResult[]'

Tags: c#

I am trying to extend a program with a language code detection but I get this Error when i try to implement it.

Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<DetectLanguage.DetectResult[]>' to 'DetectLanguage.DetectResult[]'

```
private static Translation Translate(string sourceText, string lang)
        {
            DetectLanguageClient client = new DetectLanguageClient("API KEY");
            DetectResult[] results = client.DetectAsync(sourceText);

[...]
```

using the https://detectlanguage.com/ API

Comment: You have an async method that needs to be awaited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API that you're calling returns a `Task<T>`, which is essentially an async operation - not the result of such.

To get the actual result of the async operation, you need to use `await`.  Since `await` can only be used inside an async function, you also need to declare your `Translate` function as such;

```
private static async Task<Translation> Translate(string sourceText, string lang)
        {
            DetectLanguageClient client = new DetectLanguageClient("API KEY");
            DetectResult[] results = await client.DetectAsync(sourceText);
```

Comment: Return value must be a task type

Comment: @CodeCaster I assumed that the OP wants to do something with the return value of that function and not just return it - because the function returns a "Translation" object, but the async an array of "DetectResult".